Splitting dag dependencies in python
Splitting dag dependencies in Python
I tried implementing a script for splitting dag dependencies, my goal is to split the node dependencies so that for each node that has more then one dependency, I would duplicate the node until it has one dependency
(the sub dependecies of the duplicated node also need to be duplicated),
I tried to use the bread-first search algorithm for that but I'm not sure if it's the right way.
for example for a this dag:
[example dag]: (https://i.sstatic.net/WqgJoDwX.png)
I expect to get the following result: (https://i.sstatic.net/829jW9yT.png)
Assume that I'm provided with the following dag dependencies in a dict formant:
    dag_dependencies = {
    'A': ['B', 'C'],
    'B': ['D'],
    'C': ['D'],
    'D': ['E', 'F'],
    'E': [],
    'F': [],
}


I expect to get:
    expected_dag_dependencies = {
    'A': ['B', 'C'],
    'B': ['D1'],
    'C': ['D2'],
    'D1': ['E1', 'F1'],
    'D2': ['E2', 'F2'],
    'E1': [],
    'F1': [],
    'E2': [],
    'F2': [],
}

how to implement this on python?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

"I tried to use the bread-first search algorithm for that but I'm not sure if it's the right way.": What problem did you encounter? Did you get the right output? Can you explain the problem you have in doing this? Some code?

You can use a depth-first traversal on each "root" in your DAG, collecting the tree that can be reached from such root.
Then see which node names occur more than once, and then number those while creating the new data structure:
from collections import Counter

def split_dag(dag):
    def dfs(node):
        counter[node] += 1
        return [node, *map(dfs, dag[node])]

    def save(tree):
        node, *children = tree
        if node in dupes:
            dupes[node] += 1
            node = f"{node}{dupes[node]}"
        forest[node] = list(map(save, children))
        return node

    counter = Counter()
    forest = {}
    roots = set(dag.keys()).difference(node for neighbors in dag.values() 
                                            for node in neighbors)
    trees = list(map(dfs, roots))
    dupes = { node: 0 for node, freq in counter.items() if freq > 1 }
    for tree in trees:
        save(tree)
    return forest

Here is how you can run it with your example:
dag_dependencies = {
    'A': ['B', 'C'],
    'B': ['D'],
    'C': ['D'],
    'D': ['E', 'F'],
    'E': [],
    'F': [],
}

forest = split_dag(dag_dependencies)
print(forest)


Run the script as is to see the original and split DAG structures printed. You can also modify according to your usecase(if any).
from collections import deque

class Node:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []
        self.parents = []

def split_dag(root):
    queue = deque([root])
    visited = set()
    new_nodes = {}

    while queue:
        node = queue.popleft()
        if node in visited:
            continue
        visited.add(node)

        for child in node.children:
            if len(child.parents) > 1:
                # Create a new node
                new_name = f"{child.name}_{node.name}"
                if new_name not in new_nodes:
                    new_nodes[new_name] = Node(new_name)
                new_node = new_nodes[new_name]

                # Update relationships
                new_node.children = child.children.copy()
                node.children[node.children.index(child)] = new_node
                new_node.parents = [node]

                # Update child's relationships
                child.parents.remove(node)
                for grandchild in child.children:
                    grandchild.parents.append(new_node)

                queue.append(new_node)
            else:
                queue.append(child)

    return root

# Helper function to create the initial DAG
def create_dag():
    nodes = {name: Node(name) for name in 'ABCD1D2E1F1E2F2'}
    
    edges = [
        ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'B'),
        ('C', 'D1'), ('B', 'D2'),
        ('D1', 'E1'), ('D1', 'F1'),
        ('D2', 'E2'), ('D2', 'F2')
    ]

    for parent, child in edges:
        nodes[parent].children.append(nodes[child])
        nodes[child].parents.append(nodes[parent])

    return nodes['A']

# Function to print the DAG structure
def print_dag(root, prefix=""):
    print(f"{prefix}{root.name}")
    for child in root.children:
        print_dag(child, prefix + "  ")

# Main execution
root = create_dag()
print("Original DAG:")
print_dag(root)

split_root = split_dag(root)
print("\nSplit DAG:")
print_dag(split_root)



Hey, the code returns a key Error in the create_dag() function. In addition i updated the question to be more specific to the result i would like to get :)
